# Locate text position, extract text and insert in new column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, return-value, extract

I have the following example of rows in a MySQl table

```
              Column A    

Row1    Lauguage=English&Country=USA&Gender=Male
Row2    Gender=Female&Language=French&Country=
Row3    Country=Canada&Gender=&Language=English
```

How can I achieve the following: For example, I need to look for Country

1. I need to locate the position of Country in this text column. This changes from row to row.
2. I need to then ignore the parameter 'Country=' and only extract the value. In some cases this will be NULL (like example in Row2) while in some rows I need the values followed by '=' (like example in Row1 & Row3). But, I need to make sure I get the value only. Not the next parameter separated by '&'
3. Once I have extracted the values of the Country parameter, I need to create a new column where these values will now be extracted and stored.

End Result: New Column

```
              Column B                                                

Row1            USA                            
Row2                              
Row3           Canada
```

Any help here would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you putting data like this in your table? Normalize!

Comment: Use the `LOCATE()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions. Unfortunately, it's complicated in SQL, because you need to use nested calls to `LOCATE()` to find the `&` that ends it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can pick the text following the 'Country=', and then once you have that substring, pick the text before the first '&'

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnA, 'Country=', -1), '&', 1) AS ColumnB
FROM `atable`
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

---

Here's a test to demonstrate:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM atable;
+------+------------------------------------------+
| row  | columna                                  |
+------+------------------------------------------+
| Row1 | Lauguage=English&Country=USA&Gender=Male |
| Row2 | Gender=Female&Language=French&Country=   |
| Row3 | Country=Canada&Gender=&Language=English  |
+------+------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnA, 'Country=', -1), '&', 1) AS ColumnB FROM atable;
+---------+
| ColumnB |
+---------+
| USA     |
|         |
| Canada  |
+---------+
```

---

Re your followup question:

```
INSERT INTO atable VALUES ('Row4', 'Gender=&Language=English');

SELECT `row`, IF(LOCATE('Country=', ColumnA)>0, 
  COALESCE(
    NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnA, 'Country=', -1), '&', 1), ''), 
    'Blank string is not valid!'), 
 'Missing Country!') AS ColumnB     
FROM `atable`

+------+----------------------------+
| row  | ColumnB                    |
+------+----------------------------+
| Row1 | USA                        |
| Row2 | Blank string is not valid! |
| Row3 | Canada                     |
| Row4 | Missing Country!           |
+------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems to work only for the example in Row3.
The parameter Country= is not consistent in its position. It could be the 1st parameter or it could be the 5th.
Is there a way to locate Country= and then look for the next '&' and get the value to be displayed? Tried in excel:
1. Column data stored in A1
2. FIND("Country=",A1) -> (Position of Country) stored in column B1
3. IFERROR(FIND("="A1,B1),LEN(A1) -> (Position of =) stored in column C1
4. IFERROR(FIND("&",A1,C1),LEN(A1)+1) -> (Position of end) stored in column D1
5. MID(A1,C1+1,D1-C1-1) -> displays the Country value in cell E1

Comment: @Nowitz41, I tested it and included the output above.

Comment: Thanks for your output. This is working now!
Quick follow-up, for Rows where parameter Country= is either blank (ex: Country=&) and where Country= is not present, is there a way to add this error check capability as well? So that is only updates those rows where Country= has a 'valid' value. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nowitz41, great, I'm glad to help. By the way, it is customary on StackOverflow to mark helpful answers with an up vote or 'accepted answer'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question however, in SQL for anyone wanting the SQL answer see Tim Biegeleisen comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58691164/locate-value-in-column)

```
create table elb_logs(row varchar(100), url varchar(100));
insert into elb_logs values("Row1", "Lauguage=English&Country=USA&Gender=Male");

SELECT
    row,
    CASE WHEN POSITION('Country=' IN url) > 0
         THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(url, 'Country=', 2), '&', 1)
         ELSE 'Missing Country!' END AS ColumnB
FROM elb_logs;
```