# Locate value in column

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am passing Elastic Load Balancing Access logs to Athena and I want to get a value that is located in the URL column. The below works for mySQL but Athena uses SQL is there a way I can grab the value of county from the below?

```
create table elb_logs(row varchar(100), url varchar(100));
insert into elb_logs values("Row1", "Lauguage=English&Country=USA&Gender=Male");
insert into elb_logs values("Row2", "Gender=Female&Language=French&Country=");
insert into elb_logs values("Row3", "Country=Canada&Gender=&Language=English");
insert into elb_logs values("Row4", "Gender=&Language=English");

SELECT `row`, IF(LOCATE('Country=', url)>0, 
  COALESCE(
    NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'Country=', -1), '&', 1), ''), 
    'Blank string is not valid!'), 
 'Missing Country!') AS ColumnB     
FROM `elb_logs`
```

```
+------+----------------------------+
| row  | ColumnB                    |
+------+----------------------------+
| Row1 | USA                        |
| Row2 | Blank string is not valid! |
| Row3 | Canada                     |
| Row4 | Missing Country!           |
+------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SPLIT_PART` function would seem to be usable here:

```
SELECT
    row,
    CASE WHEN POSITION('Country=' IN url) > 0
         THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(url, 'Country=', 2), '&', 1)
         ELSE 'Missing Country!' END AS ColumnB
FROM elb_log;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ive adapted this to what i need. Do you know how I can GROUP BY row, ColumnB. As you can't GROUP BY an ailas.

Comment: @mRyan You either have to repeat the entire case expression for `ColumnB`, or subquery my answer, and then refer to `ColumnB` in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cross Apply`

```
SELECT row, CASE WHEN LEFT(T2.URL, charindex('&', T2.URL) - 1) = '' THEN 'Blank string is not valid!' 
                 WHEN LEFT(T2.URL, charindex('&', T2.URL) - 1) LIKE '%=%' THEN 'Missing Country!' 
            ELSE LEFT(T2.URL, charindex('&', T2.URL) - 1)   END AS Country
FROM elb_logs AS T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF(T.URL, 1, charindex('&Country', T.URL) + 8, '')+'&') as T2(URL);
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server syntax, which is not what this question is about.